# ¿Cómo llamaríais a una persona que suele ser origen de envidias?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Tengo un primo que se dedica de forma profesional al esquí, y ahora es el entrenador del equipo femenino olímpico de esquí alpino canadiense. Como podéis imaginar, recorre el mundo de competición en competición y también buscando lugares donde entrenarse, y cada cierto tiempo nos envía fotos de los sitios donde está, generando envidias (sanas) en la familia.

Y la pregunta que se me ocurre es: ¿qué palabra se usaría para designar a una persona que es propensa a generar envidias en los demás?

Se me ocurría *envidiable*, pero según el diccionario, su significado es "digno de ser deseado y apetecido". Entiendo pues que yo usaría la palabra *envidiable* para describir la situación o el lugar en el que se encuentra esa persona, pero no a la persona en sí. Busco una palabra del tipo de *agresiva* (que indica que una persona es propensa a la violencia, aunque no siempre sea violenta): una persona que por el motivo que sea es propensa a despertar envidias (pero no hacia sí misma). Y si es posible, que no sean insultos: "qué *cabrón* el tío este, mira dónde está ahora".

Comment: No veo porque no usar *envidiable* con una persona (igual que usamos *deseable*), creo que es la palabra adecuada, tampoco se me ocurre ninguna otra. También se podría decir «que causa/provoca envidia»

Comment: Recalcas mucho lo de envidia _sana_, ¿estás seguro o es que te lo repites para convencerte? :P

Comment: @fedorqui estoy seguro. :-)

Comment: @blonfu yo usaría _envidiable_ con la persona si fuera la misma persona en sí la que me causa envidia (es decir, yo quiero ser esa persona), pero no es el caso. Yo no quiero ser esa persona, pero sí me gustaría estar en los mismos lugares que ella, por ejemplo. Luego la persona no es _envidiable_, pero sí es causa de muchas envidias.

Comment: Entonces lo envidiable es su trabajo, o sus viajes

Comment: @blonfu exacto, pero me gustaría saber si existe algún adjetivo aplicable a la persona que es causa de esas envidias.

Comment: No entiendo la diferencia que haces: causa envidia pero no es envidiable

Comment: Yo usaría: digno de envidia.

Comment: @blonfu entiendo la confusión. Si crees que "envidiable" es el término correcto, lo puedes proponer como respuesta. En todo caso, la distinción la has hecho tú mismo: mi primo me genera envidias, no porque él sea envidiable, sino porque sus viajes (o su trabajo, o lo que sea) son envidiables. El adjetivo se aplica a sus viajes, no a él.

Comment: Ahora he leído mejor la pregunta y según la definición del DLE creo que entiendo lo que quieres decir. Yo había asumido que envidiable es algo digno de envidia, como lo definen otros diccionarios.

Comment: Yo usaría **"objeto de envidias"**. Buscando un poco he encontrado [changüí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8YviZcH) "loc. verb. R. Dom. Hacer algo para generar envidia.", pero no aplica en este caso, porque entiendo que el término que tú buscas no implica esa intencionalidad (aparte de que esta es una locución coloquial de la República Dominicana)

Comment: @Diego Otra posibilidad: "blanco de todas las envidas".

Comment: @Gustavson, esa es buena también e implica, como busca el OP, que esa persona es propensa a la envidia de otros sin buscar activamente generar dicho sentimiento en otros. Si sacas tiempo proponlas como respuesta. Yo no sé si existirá o encontraremos un término único, y ese que propones tú es el yo creo que mejor describe lo que buscamos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esto es un poco una respuesta a medias, pero yo usaría su vida como sujeto de la envidia:

> Juan tiene una vida envidiable, está siempre viajando y conociendo gente interesante.

Answer (score 1):

Te ofrezco varias opciones, para el caso de la persona inspira envidia sin andar buscándola (que entendí que es el caso de tu primo).

> ***Lleva una vida encantada***.  Mi primo de la vida encantada etc.
>
> Mi primo ***de la jet set*** etc.
>
> (Sarcastico) Mi primo ***que tiene la vida perfecta*** etc.  O: Mi primo, él de la vida perfecta, etc.

Versión súper respetuosa:

> Mi primo ***admirable*** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría, además de las otras respuestas, "tentador" o "provocador" (en el buen sentido, como cuando te ofrecen una bandeja de postres o algo así). Parece que el adjetivo "envidiable" tiene que ver más con "incitador" (que es lo que da esa pequeña "rabia") que con "deseable" (que es más sano jaja)